# Support status for Apple M2 chip

Tags: dev

2022 Apple macbook pros all comes with M2 chips. Before buying one, I want to double check about the current support status of the M2 chips with the Substrate/Polkadot codebase.

1. Is M2 chips compatibility tested for the Substrate + polkadot codebase?
2. Anyone currently do substrate (or related) development on M2 laptops?

Any info are appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Are M2 chips different in compatibility to M1? I think not, since they are both ARM based, so it should work just fine. I use an M1 macbook to do daily development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a macbook air with the M2 chip and it works perfectly fine. It gets a little bit hot when you compile for the first time (after that it doesn't), but you won't notice it unless you use the top most keys. I think the macbook pro comes with vents so that could help a little bit for compilations.